# SQL query- turning daily data to average for month, cumulative sum until end of month?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sum, average

SQL - turning daily data  to average for month, cumulative sum until end of month

I have daily data coming from a database. 
It has a table  that contains many columns - Date, Entity Name, Value1, value2, value3, ..
I want to work out the average value per month for each entity. Also for certain values, i need the cumulative sum value from the beginning to until end of the month (cumulative sum by end of the month).

Example:

```
Date          Entity    Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4

01/01/2017  'ZZ-01'     5       10      25          10

01/01/2017  'BB-01'     5       10      25          10

02/01/2017  'ZZ-01'     2       1       5           0

02/01/2017  'BB-01'     2       1       5           0

03/01/2017  'ZZ-01'     5       10      25          10

03/01/2017  'BB-01'     5       10      25          10

.....

.....  

31/01/2017  'ZZ-01'     5       10      25          10

31/01/2017  'BB-01'     5       10      25          5

01/02/2017  'ZZ-01'     5       10      25          15

01/02/2017  'BB-01'     5       10      25          11

02/02/2017  'ZZ-01'     5       10      25          15

.......  

28/02/2017  'ZZ-01'     5       10      25          10

28/02/2017  'BB-01'     5       10      25          10

....
```

and so on

What I would like to create is a table that looks like:

```
Month       Entity      AvgValue1   AvgValue2  CumValue2   AvgValue3    AvgValue4

Jan-2017    'ZZ-01'      Avg1        Avg2       CumV2       Avg3        Avg4        
Jan-2017    'BB-01'             
Feb-2017    'ZZ-01'             
Feb-2017    'BB-01'             
Mar-2017    'ZZ-01'         
...
```

Average for the given month for each values. For some values, i need cumulative sum until end of month since the beginning of the data in the table.

from searching the stackoverflow, I found out that i can use the below  to get the sum and cumulative

```
  SELECT Date, Name, Sum, Avg,   
  (SELECT SUM(Value1)  
  FROM mytable as t2  
  Where t2.Date <=t1.Date) as CumVal  
  from mytable as t1
  order by t1.DateO ASC, Name
```

and below for average for month

```
 SELECT 
dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, t2.Date), 0) as Month,   
AVG(t2.Value1) as AvgValue1  
FROM mytable as t2  
group by dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, t2.Date), 0)
```

But I am not able to combine these things to make one single query that helps in creating the table.  your help is appreciated.

I tried to create small test code with one value column:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.mytable', 'U') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
DROP TABLE dbo.mytable
END
CREATE TABLE mytable
([DateOn] datetime, [Name] varchar(10), [Rate1] float, [Rate2] float, 
[Rate3] float)
 ;

INSERT INTO mytable
([DateOn], [Name], [Rate1])
VALUES
 -- MM/DD/YYYY format
 -- value for first 4 days is shown. assume that the rest days are zero
 -- average will be (sum /31) in January
  ('01/01/2017' , 'AA-01',    10),
  ('01/01/2017' , 'BB-01',    100),
  ('01/02/2017' , 'AA-01',    15),
  ('01/02/2017' , 'BB-01',    200),
  ('01/03/2017' , 'AA-01',    20),
  ('01/03/2017' , 'BB-01',    300),
  ('01/04/2017' , 'AA-01',    25),
  ('01/04/2017' , 'BB-01',    400),
  ('02/01/2017' , 'AA-01',    10),
  ('02/01/2017' , 'BB-01',    100),
  ('02/02/2017' , 'AA-01',    15),
  ('02/02/2017' , 'BB-01',    200),
  ('02/03/2017' , 'AA-01',    20),
  ('02/03/2017' , 'BB-01',    300),
  ('02/04/2017' , 'AA-01',    25),
  ('02/04/2017' , 'BB-01',    400)
  ;   
Select dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, t1.DateOn), 0) as Month, Name,
 AVG(t1.Rate1) as AvgRate1,
 (
  SELECT SUM(Rate1)
  FROM mytable as t2
  Where t2.DateOn <=t1.DateOn
   )
   as CumRate
  from mytable as t1
  --order by t1.DateOn ASC,Name
  group by dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, t1.DateOn), 0)
  DROP TABLE dbo.mytable
```

I am running this test on
https://rextester.com/CFHEW85984

but getting an error:

Error(s), warning(s):
 Column 'mytable.DateOn' is invalid in the select list because it is not 
 contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Column 'mytable.Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

expected result table format:

```
  Month     Name    AvgRate    CumRate
   Jan-17   AA-01    2.258       70
   Jan-17   BB-01     32.258     1000
   Feb-17   AA-01     2.5        140
   Feb-27   BB-01     35.714     2000
```

so for Jan-17 for name AA-01, i add up the daily figures (only 4 days in this example, rest assumed 0) and divide by 31 to get avg for the month. I then sum them up to get cumulative. For February, average is done same way w, but cumulative is cum_jan+cum_feb. so on

I am struggling how to combine this with join also.

## Thanks

Comment: pick ONE single SQL server type only. Format your SQL/tables too please.

Comment: You need to group by Entity as well also add avg value 2, 3, 4 like you did for Avg value 1. I don't think you may need that date add thing,  You can just do Month(column name) if the data is for one year, else add Month(column)+ year(column) name.

Comment: I tried to add small test to show what i am trying to achieve. thanks a lot for your support.

Comment: your description is not clear, try to simply write out the expected result set of your small test code's table. instead of only the column header name

Comment: also your small test code's table didn't contain a same month/code, thus no grouping can be illustrated

Comment: I have tried once again to make the question clear. thanks for the help

Comment: @Avi Could you please explain little more.  the data is for several years.